# Is it safe to use spring cloud GREENWICH.SR3 version? Is it a stable version? Or should we have to stick with GREENWICH.RELEASE flavor?

Tags: spring-boot

GREENWICH.RELEASE was released by the beginning of this year while SR3 is recently released. Can anyone explain what service release (SR) means? Is it same as SNAPSHOT and will be changed frequently? Or are they fairly stable versions that can be used in a production environment?

Answer (score 4):

An SR means Service Release (subsequent maintenance releases that come after major RELEASE), it's completely stable and can be used on production.